# WPF Image with two sources

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I'd like to extend Image class by adding second source. I want to define second source in XAML (like original source) and change these images when mouse enters/leaves this image.

I tried myself with:

```
class MainMenuImageButton : Image
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty Source2Property;
        public ImageSource Source2 
        {
            get { return Source2; }
            set
            {
                this.MouseEnter+=new System.Windows.Input.MouseEventHandler(MainMenuImageButton_MouseEnter);
            }
        }
        public void MainMenuImageButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Source = Source2;
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work and I think I do it tottaly wrong. Can somebody help?

**[UPDATE]**

I wrote this:

```
class MainMenuImageButton : Image
{
    protected override HitTestResult HitTestCore(PointHitTestParameters hitTestParameters)
    {
        var source = (BitmapSource)Source;
        var x = (int)(hitTestParameters.HitPoint.X / ActualWidth * source.PixelWidth);
        var y = (int)(hitTestParameters.HitPoint.Y / ActualHeight * source.PixelHeight);
        var pixels = new byte[4];
        source.CopyPixels(new Int32Rect(x, y, 1, 1), pixels, 4, 0);
        if (pixels[3] < 10) return null;
        return new PointHitTestResult(this, hitTestParameters.HitPoint);
    }
    public ImageSource Source1
    {
        get { return GetValue(ImageSourceProperty) as ImageSource; }
        set { base.SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Source1", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(MainMenuImageButton));
    public ImageSource Source2
    {
        get { return GetValue(ImageSource2Property) as ImageSource; }
        set { base.SetValue(ImageSource2Property, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSource2Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Source2", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(MainMenuImageButton));
    public MainMenuImageButton() : base() 
    {
        this.MouseEnter += new MouseEventHandler(MainMenuImageButton_MouseEnter);
        this.MouseLeave += new MouseEventHandler(MainMenuImageButton_MouseLeave);
    }

    void MainMenuImageButton_MouseLeave(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Source = this.Source1;
    }

    void MainMenuImageButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Source = this.Source2;
    }
}
```

But sometimes it works and sometimes there is exception: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in PresentationCore.dll

Additional information: The value is outside the expected range."

---

I'm not sure if I understood, but I tried this:

```
class MainMenuImageButton : Image
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty Source2Property = DependencyProperty.Register("Source2", typeof(ImageSource), typeof(MainMenuImageButton), new PropertyMetadata(true));
    public ImageSource Source2 
    {
        get { return (ImageSource)GetValue(Source2Property); }
        set
        {
            BitmapImage logo = new BitmapImage(new Uri(value.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
            SetValue(Source2Property, logo); 
            this.MouseEnter+=new System.Windows.Input.MouseEventHandler(MainMenuImageButton_MouseEnter);
        }
    }
    public void MainMenuImageButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        this.Source = Source2;
    }
}
```

And still nothing. Wham am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change an image on hover over in WPF?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502914/how-do-i-change-an-image-on-hover-over-in-wpf)

Comment: One you have a loop on the get.  Two why are you wiring up the event handler in the set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Refer to the [Custom Dependency Properties article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753358.aspx). The event hookup belongs in your dependency property's `PropertyChangedCallback`.

I would also suggest using a trigger instead of event handling. However, this doesn't mean you will need to duplicate the XAML everywhere you want to use it. You could define a custom control with the image switching trigger in its default style (see "Defining Resources at the Theme Level" in the [Control Authoring Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745025.aspx)). Where `MouseOverImage` is a `Control` with "Source" and "Source2" dependency properties, you could define this default style:

```
<Style TargetType="local:MouseOverImage">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:MouseOverImage">
                <Grid>
                    <Image Name="SourceImage" Source="{TemplateBinding Source}" />
                    <Image Name="Source2Image" Source="{TemplateBinding Source2}" Visibility="Hidden" />
                </Grid>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="SourceImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden" />
                        <Setter TargetName="Source2Image" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

If you use event handlers, you would need to store the original value of Source, add a `MouseLeave` handler that reverts it, and also consider the case where a user reassigns `Source` or `Source2` at any time. Using the trigger solution with two separate "Source" and "Source2" bindings, all of this is handled automatically.

**EDIT**

> But sometimes it works and sometimes there is exception: "An unhandled
>   exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   PresentationCore.dll
>
> Additional information: The value is outside the expected range."

My guess is that `HitTestCore` is firing after the source changes but before it's applied to the layout, so there is a discrepancy between `ActualWidth` and `source.PixelWidth`. I am not sure of the rationale for including these in the calculation (shouldn't they always be the same?) Try just using the following:

```
var x = (int)hitTestParameters.HitPoint.X;
var y = (int)hitTestParameters.HitPoint.Y;
```

Comment: But I also want to override HitTestCore method to react only with nontransparent field and ude it like a button.

Comment: @petros It might be easier to extend Image then. I would go with a separate property to the define the "normal" source, and use [SetBinding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingoperations.setbinding.aspx) in the `MouseEnter` / `MouseLeave` handlers to bind `Source` to either `Source1` or `Source2`. That way both properties can be bound independently without one overwriting the other when the mouse moves.

Comment: I tried your version but then it was reacting only in bottom left corner, so I returned my version. But you're right that it's something with HitTestCore. I used try-catch and it doesn't throw exceptions now. But I know that try-catch solution is not the best.

Comment: @petros The exception would be caused by x or y being out of range (0 to (PixelWidth - 1), and 0 to (PixelHeight - 1)). You could check for this yourself and adjust x or y to the closest valid value (minimum or maximum) when they are invalid.

Comment: I tried source.PixelWidth-1 and source.PixelHeight-1 and it seems to work. Debugger haven't riched the breakpoint in catch block yet. Thanks for help

Answer (score 4):

Extending Image Is an overkill, all you have to do is define a style which will use trigger to swap the sources

```
<Image>
  <Image.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
      <Setter Property="Source" Value="Image1"/>
      <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
          <Setter Property="Source" Value="Image2"/>
        </Trigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </Image.Style>
</Image>
```

Comment: But where do I select Image1 and Image2?

Comment: @petros you supply the path to `Image1` and `Image2` in your style. You can also bind to an `ImageSource` on your viewmodel or code-behind instead, if you don't want to hardcode an image resource path.

Comment: And if I want to use this style in more than one cotrol? Do I have to write different style for each one? (e.g. I have 2 Image controls and each one has 2 different sources)

Comment: @petros Go to msdn.microsoft.com and search on wpf style.  What have you tried?

Comment: @Blam, in your solution I have to select Image2 in style (I think so), but I want select it like:
<Image Source="a.png" Source2="b.png"/>

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to extend the `Image` class to do this. There is a property on the `Image` class called `IsMouseOver` that you can trigger on to switch the `Source` of your image. Put this in a style on your view and you'll be all set.

Comment: Yes, but I will use this class often, so I want to do it only by defining image fila

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the new property as a `Dependency Property`. You can find out more from the [DependencyProperties Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx) page at MSDN, but the basic idea is this:

You first create the `Dependency Property`:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSpinningProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
"IsSpinning", typeof(Boolean), typeof(YourClassName), new PropertyMetadata(true));
```

Then you *can* optionally add a wrapper using standard CLR properties (for your own use only):

```
public bool IsSpinning
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSpinningProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsSpinningProperty, value); }
}
```

(Code example was taken from the linked article)