# Change button when hovered

Tags: c#, wpf

I am a beginner and I am looking for a simple way to make a button in WPF application move when it is hovered over.

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

}
private void btnNo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: Code would help.  See here, but instead of changing image source property change position [how-do-i-change-an-image-on-hover-over-in-wpf](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502914/how-do-i-change-an-image-on-hover-over-in-wpf)

Comment: ...and the down vote wasn't me, as I would never down vote someone's first question here as a matter of principle.  Shrug it off.  Just be sure to do a tiny bit more research, and post your current code no matter how simple it is.  That gives us something to talk about and shows your willingness to compose a thorough post.

Comment: I did not post any code because I did not have anything, can't even find anything good on google... I added the button code though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may put the `Button` in a [`Grid`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.grid(v=vs.110).aspx), and changes its [`Margin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.margin.aspx) in the button's [`MouseEnter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter(v=vs.110).aspx) event, like this:

```
private void ChangePosition(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var button = (Button)sender;
    var newPosition = new Thickness(10, 90, 40, 80); // assuming this is your new position
    button.Margin = newPosition;
}
```

Comment: This worked, but I would like for it to do it indefinitely, where it will keep changing position everytime hovered on... it works only once atm

Comment: The `newPosition` in the code is  always the same as an example. You may set the `newPosition` based on the current position.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want it to move back when you cease to hover over it, you can do this in pure XAML by using a style and a property trigger on the Button's IsMouseOver property. (A more typical use of style would be to create it as a resource and share it across various buttons).

```
    <Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" Height="40" Width="60">
        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <TranslateTransform X="10" Y="10"/>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```