# How to show images in C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I am a first year computer science student and I am having a really hard time with C#. I have been given a task where I have to create a wpf, where images have to appear and when my mouse lands on those images they have to become blurry. But I can't get my images to show up and I don't know why. They are correct in my XAML (I have no error messages) and I coded them as my course said so : `img(name).Source = new BitmapImages(new Uri(@"image/(name).png", UriKind.Relative));` but for some reason it doesn't work and I don't understand why and I don't want to use ChatGPT, hopefully you guys can help me.

i tried:

```
img(name).Source = new BitmapImages(new Uri(@"image/(name).png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
```

i also tried:

```
BitmapImage (name) = new BitmapImage(new Uri("img/(name).png", UriKind.Relative));
img(name).Source = (name);
```

So normally as soon as I start my wpf the images should be there and when my mouse passes over the image it should become blurred.

Comment: please post a fully reproductible example

Answer (score 0):

The following should help get you started. It shows how to load an image. As far as blurring the image, I'll leave that for you to complete.

**VS 2022**

Create a new project with name ImageTest. From the project templates choose

- **WPF App (.NET Framework)** when you want to use the old `.NET Framework` or
- **WPF Application** when you want to use the new `.NET`

Open Solution Explorer

- In VS menu, click **View**
- Select **Solution Explorer**

Add image(s) to solution

- In Solution Explorer, right click <project name> (ex: ImageTest)
- Select **Add**
- Select **New Folder** (name: Images)
- In Solution Explorer, right-click the folder you just created (ex: Images), select **Add**
- Select **Existing Item...**
- For filter, select:
  [image]
- Select desired image (ex: Apple.png)
- Open the **Properties** dialog from the context menu of the image file
- Select **Resource** as **Build Action** of the file

In Solution Explorer, you'll now see the following:

[image]

**MainWindow.xaml**:

```
<Window x:Class="ImageTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Loaded="Window_Loaded"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="200" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <!-- image control -->
        <Image Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="image1" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.xaml.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ImageTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // While a relative URI as shown below also works, the correct
            // way to load an image resource is by means of a WPF Pack Uri
            //
            // Uri imgUri = new Uri("/Images/Apple.png", UriKind.Relative);

            Uri imgUri = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Images/Apple.png");
            image1.Source = new BitmapImage(imgUri);
        }
    }
}
```

**Resources**:

- [The Image control](https://wpf-tutorial.com/basic-controls/the-image-control/)
- [How to: Use the Image Element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-use-the-image-element?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
- [How do I change an image on hover over in WPF?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1502914/how-do-i-change-an-image-on-hover-over-in-wpf)